# border radius not working in android 2.3.4

Tags: css, android-browser

border radius not working in android 2.3.4

Example:

```
.radius5 {
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: According to [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius), Android 2.3.4 should support `border-radius` with no prefixing.

Comment: `Android Browser 2.3 does not support % value for border-radius.`

Comment: Thanks James... But android native browser not support...

Comment: Yes you are right but "px" getting pixelated Vucko....

Answer (score 1):

The issues stated [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius) (henceforth by Armarnath Balasubramani) are valid.

But heres what you can do for a quick fix ! :)

```
    #circle {
      border-radius: 9999px; /* the css3 circle */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - use Opera Mini
2 - try to make radius with pixels (1px) or ems (1em)

Comment: This is not really a solution, you can't force people to use another browser. The second option however is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an issue in this: [check here, and click on known issues.](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius)

Here's what it says:

```
1. Android Browser 2.3 does not support % value for border-radius.

2. Border-radius does not work on fieldset elements in IE9.

3. The stock browser on the Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 4.2 does not support the "border-radius" shorthand property but does support the long-hand properties for each corner like "border-top-left-radius".
```